# For Loop not executing

Tags: c, for-loop

The formula simply isn't executing. I tried using `printf` to debug and it printed out 0 for `i` at the end of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i, base, height;
 printf("Lumber  Cross-Sectional   Moment of Section\n");
 printf("Size  Area    Inertia  Modulus\n");
 for (i = 0; i > 35; i++)
 {
  if (i == 6 || i == 12 || i == 18|| i == 24 || i == 30)
  {
   base = base * 2;
   height = 2;
  }
  if (i != 6 || i != 12 || i != 18 || i != 24 || i != 30)
  {
   height = height * 2;
  }
  printf("%d x %d %d  %d   %d \n", base, height, base * height, base * 2 + height); 

 }//for  
 return (0);
}//main
```

Comment: Another bug -- don't assume base=0 and height=0 at the beginning of the loop. They could be anything.

Comment: Looking at your other questions, you seem to not understand how certain constructs work, and you don't know how to use a debugger (for stepping through code, checking variable values and showing you how it skips over the loop).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 35; i++)
```

The body of the loop will only execute when the condition is true.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 35; i++)
```

as said by Bill the Lizard.

```
for (i = 0; i > 35; i++)
```

is never true in its condition since 0 < 35 and hence the loop body is never executed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to think what your conditions mean.  The reason the loop doesn't execute is mentioned by others.  Let's look at the other condition:

```
if (i != 6 || i != 12 || i != 18 || i != 24 || i != 30)
```

When do you think the above condition will be false?  We need to look at two cases:

- `i` is equal to 6.  So, `i != 6` is false, but every other part of the condition (`i != 12`, etc.) is true.  This is because 6 is only equal to 6, and no other number.  So the overall condition is true.
- `i` is not equal to 6.  Now, `i != 6` is true, and therefore the whole condition is true.

So, your `if` condition above is always true.

Also, think about what would happen if you were looping till a large number, let's say 215.  Will you want to have a condition like:

```
if (i == 6 || i == 12 || ... || i == 210)
```

Surely, there has to be a better to do what you want.  I think what you want is to multiply `base` by 2, and reset `height` when `i` is divisible by 6; otherwise multiply `height` by 2.  The code structure becomes:

```
/* not legal C */
if (i is divisible by 6) {
} else {
}
```

To test divisibility by 6, remember that for numbers `n` and `m`, `n % m` gives you the remainder of `n` divided by `m`.

Answer (score 0):

As said by the above two mates 
for loop will not execute until the condition is true. Before asking it here you should have debugged it yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you reshape the code and the conditions, it will be lot better. 
Can you change the for loop to `for (i=1 ; i<36 ; i++)`? This way you can simplify the if condition inside the loop,as you can see you are checking if its a multiple of 6 in the code. 
You can just think on those lines.

Some more pointers:

1. Initialize all variables to default values.
2. Print the output in better readable way. Delete x from it. Also space the values equally using \t.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop will  never execute.First time for checks for the (i>35), in your case i<35, so the loop will not execute.